# I need help regrading deleting items inside RecyclerView. Deletion works but updating RecyclerView sometimes doesn't work after deletion

Tags: java, android

Sometimes delete function works sometimes not. I think the problem is with the notifyItemRemove or removing items inside the array. Worked on finding the bug for 3 days but in vain.
This is the adapter class

```
public class ChecklistItems extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

String content;
String status;

String[] contentSplit;
String[] statusSplit;

private ChecklistAdapter checklistAdapter;
DbHelper dbHelper;
List<ChecklistHelper> checks;
int id;
ChecklistHelper checklistHelper;
StringBuilder stringBuilderContent;
StringBuilder stringBuilderStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_items);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_child);


    id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
    content = getIntent().getStringExtra("content");
    status = getIntent().getStringExtra("status");

    contentSplit = content.split("\n");
    statusSplit = status.split("\n");

    checklistHelper = new ChecklistHelper();
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    checks = dbHelper.getChecklists();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
    checklistHelper =  dbHelper.getChecklists(id);
    String status = checklistHelper.getStatus();
    String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
    ArrayList<String> newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
    ArrayList<String> newContentList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));

    checklistAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(newStatusList, newContentList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(checklistAdapter);
}


public class ChecklistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> newStatusList;
    ArrayList<String> newContentList;
    
    public ChecklistAdapter( ArrayList<String> newStatusList, ArrayList<String> newContentList) {
        
        this.newStatusList = newStatusList;
        this.newContentList = newContentList;
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.checklist_layout_child, parent, false);
        return new ChecklistChildViewHolder(view);

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        ChecklistChildViewHolder checklistChildViewHolder = (ChecklistChildViewHolder) holder;
        checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(contentSplit[position]);

        boolean state;
        if (statusSplit[position].equals("1")) {
            state = true;
            checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(lineThrough(checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.getText().toString()));
        }
        else
        {
            state = false;
            checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.getText().toString());
        }
        checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(state);

        checklistChildViewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doDelete(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newStatusList.size();

    }

    public class ChecklistChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView delete, edit;

        ChecklistChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_child);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_child);
            edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_child);
            delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        public void updateVisibility(boolean isEnableDelete){

            if (isEnableDelete) {
                delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public int doDelete(int position) {

        int idd = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
        checklistHelper =  dbHelper.getChecklists(idd);

        String status = checklistHelper.getStatus();
        String content = checklistHelper.getContent();

        String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
        String[] contentSplit = content.split("\n");

        newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
        newContentList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(contentSplit));

        newStatusList.remove(position);
        newContentList.remove(position);
        
        stringBuilderStatus = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilderContent = new StringBuilder();

        for(String singleStatus : newStatusList) {
            stringBuilderStatus.append(singleStatus);
            stringBuilderStatus.append("\n");
        }

        for(String singleContent: newContentList){
            stringBuilderContent.append(singleContent);
            stringBuilderContent.append("\n");
        }
        String allStatus = stringBuilderStatus.toString();
        String allContent = stringBuilderContent.toString();
        dbHelper.updateChecklist(id,allStatus , allContent, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());

        if(allContent.length()==0) {
            dbHelper.deleteChecklist(id);
            finish();
        }
        
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemChanged(position);

        return newStatusList.size();
    }
}
```

}
I have used most of the (notify) functions which update the RecyclerView but none worked properly.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_items);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_child);
    
    id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
    content = getIntent().getStringExtra("content");
    status = getIntent().getStringExtra("status");

    contentSplit = content.split("\n");
    statusSplit = status.split("\n");

    checklistHelper = new ChecklistHelper();
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(checklistAdapter);


    checklistHelper =  dbHelper.getChecklists(id);
    String status = checklistHelper.getStatus();
    String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
    ArrayList<String> newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
    ArrayList<String> newContentList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));

    checklistAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(newStatusList, newContentList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(checklistAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `notifyItemChanged(position);`. When you remove an item, you are changing the position of all other items beyond it.

You want to use `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, newContentList.size());` as this will take into account the shifting positions.

You use `notifyItemChanged(position);` if the content of the position has changed, but the position it self remains the same.

Comment: changed the code to yours, I'll get like this, please have a look https://file.lu/d/l00

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your effort with me. Finally found the problem. I changed (position) to (holder.getLayoutPosition) inside my adapter and everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the lines in doDelete method:

```
 newStatusList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(statusSplit));
 newContentList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(contentSplit));
```

two lines will re-assign the new object and the underlay data may not locate in the same memory position as the old newStatusList and newContentList

And you can use Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() instead of notifyItemXXX

Comment: Removed the two lines but still the same.

Comment: If I press back button and return to the RecyclerView it has worked, but doing that after every deletion is not preferable. Using notifyDataSetChanged() always removes the last element.

Comment: you need to make sure that two objects, newStatusList and newContentList,  in OnCreate are the same as DoDelete.

Comment: Added the code of inside onCreate() please have a look. I'll get this in LogCat  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1 ( Deleting first item always works but after that I'll get ndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Comment: as avalerio said, every time u delete an item then the position changes. So it would be best if you did additional things to make sure the item you want to delete by comparing the item content, not position.

Comment: When I get indexOutOfBoundsException it will point to this line  newStatusList.remove(position); which makes the problem

Comment: every time the adapter changes, the onBindViewHolder may be called. What I to do in the this case is use a global map object to store a unique value as key the to make sure the item value. And the map value is UI objects. Every time the onBindViewHolder called , the map will be updated. Every time the underlay data changed, use iteration to search item position in the map and do the thing that I want.

Comment: The problem here is always get the old position inside onBindViewHolder. The fix for this I think that every time the delete button clicked restore the position, if not always get the old position. What if I make an interface and pass the position from onBindViewHolder to a method and then do the deletion process in that method?

Comment: you can ref the android api:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your effort with me. Finally found the problem. I changed position() to holder.getLayoutPosition() inside my adapter and everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is not to use position variable which provided inside onBindViewHolder but instead use holder.getLayoutPosition or holder.getLayoutPosition. That is working for me.